# Starting react native app using expo not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo

Tried running 
 `expo start` `npm start` `expo-cli start` but gives the below error.

[image: Error]

Have already tried

1. Removing the .expo file before starting the bundler
2. Recloning the project
3. Tried reinstalling node modules
4. Tried reinstalling node
5. Tried various expo-cli versions, 3.20.6, 3.17, 3.14

But nothing helped.